# How to use Bootstrap's input group in simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

### Environment

- Ruby 2.5.1
- Rails 5.2.1
- Simple Form 4.0.1

### Current behavior

I follow example in http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/examples/input_group

I start with `<%= simple_form_for app, wrapper: :input_group do |f| %>` and get `Couldn't find wrapper with name input_group`, so I uncomment

```
config.wrappers :input_group, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'form-control-label'
    b.wrapper :input_group_tag, tag: 'div', class: 'input-group' do |ba|
      ba.optional :prepend
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
      ba.optional :append
    end
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback d-block' }
    b.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
  end
```

in `simple_form_bootstrap.rb`

And get `undefined method`append' for class `SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput'` instead.

Problem on this `<%= f.input :subdomain, append: "example.com" %>`

How can I use this, does this even support in simple_form? Don't know why they comment that chunk of code out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create `config/initializers/simple_form_component.rb`

```
module InputGroup
  def prepend(wrapper_options = nil)
    span_tag = content_tag(:span, options[:prepend], class: "input-group-text")
    template.content_tag(:div, span_tag, class: "input-group-prepend")
  end

  def append(wrapper_options = nil)
    span_tag = content_tag(:span, options[:append], class: "input-group-text")
    template.content_tag(:div, span_tag, class: "input-group-append")
  end
end

# Register the component in Simple Form.
SimpleForm.include_component(InputGroup)
```

[Source](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/5a876154e902126e0d5e2c546f07da90c6c37c6c/lib/components/input_group_component.rb)

Comment: Thanks, its weird that this doesn't included in the lib and have to add manually.

Comment: To use it in your form: `<%= f.input :percentage, wrapper: :input_group, append: '%' %>`

Answer (score -1):

In case somebody is wondering how to make this work. To complement [PGill's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706670/pgill) Answer. After you create the file `config/initializers/simple_form_component.rb` with the content show above.

You should go to your file `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` and on the input you are going to use add something like this:

```
b.wrapper :grid_wrapper, tag: 'div', class: 'input-group' do |ba|
  ba.optional :prepend
  ba.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: ''
  ba.optional :append
  # [...]
end
```

So your input_wrapper should look something like this:

```
  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label
    b.wrapper :grid_wrapper, tag: 'div', class: 'input-group' do |ba|
      ba.optional :prepend
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-control', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: ''
      ba.optional :append
      ba.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
      ba.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
    end
  end
```

And after that you could use it on your erb views like this:

```
 <%= f.input :attribute_name, prepend: "$" %>
```

Comment: This is not required in this example. follow the question and the selected answer only.